# Unsubscribes from mail gun

Tags: mailgun

Helpful api instructions from the great mailgun api instructions say this:
GET /[domain]/bounces
Fetches the list of unsubscribes.

when I give it:

https://api:key-[my api key here] @api.mailgun.net/v2/[my domain here]/bounces
This works  great but it only pulls down 100 as below

Parameter   Description

limit   Maximum number of records to return. (100 by default)

skip    Number of records to skip. (0 by default)

sadly here is where the instructions dry up and as I am a newby to this, I haven't been here before, I can't figure out the url to add a limit of say 300 or even skip 100 so I can get the next batch.

can anyone tell me what this might look like in an HTTP statement as above

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The parameters can be sent using a POST request using multipart form data. I know this is not documented on that page, but that's what the `curl` example does, so it must work.

Comment: Thanks but that confuses me as the HTTP I am using is a get. I don't want to add information to lists in mailgun which I have been doing, I want to download the existing lists such as bounce unsubscribe and spam. I did set it up to do it on a case by case basis but need a workaround as apparently they have a bug that doesn't allow anything with a capital letter to be downloaded on an individual basis.

Comment: To be honest no but if you have used it and it works I will give it a go, but I am struggling to work out the syntax to deliver it!